# python - pandas dataframe string search - problems with ";"?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe with a column like:

```
Proteins
Q64HY3
G3UX74;G3UY42;Q8CCS6
Q8BKC5
O70209
Q8BG32;G3UYI4;G3UYL3
```

When i want to look for strings in I go for

```
df[df['Proteins'].str.contains('Users input', na=False)
```

Which works very fine when the input is like `'G3UX74'` (3th row), and also for `'Q8CCS6'`but not if I search for example `';Q8CCS6'` or the complete string: 'G3UX74;G3UY42;Q8CCS6'.

The only thing I do on the input string is to subset for printable items to remove unwanted spaces:

```
no_space_in_string = sum(c.isprintable() for c in search_string)
search_string = search_string[:no_space_in_string]
```

So i guess it is a problem with the ';'. I can implement a warning not to use semicolons but I would like to have it flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are summing up number of `printable` characters in the input string, because `isprintable` returns True/False which is represented as 1/0 in Python:

```
In [107]: search_string
Out[107]: ';Q8CCS6'

In [108]: no_space_in_string = sum(c.isprintable() for c in search_string)

In [109]: no_space_in_string
Out[109]: 7
```

So let's try it this way:

```
In [112]: search_string = '; Q8CCS6'

In [113]: search_string.replace(' ', '')
Out[113]: ';Q8CCS6'

In [114]: search_string = search_string.replace(' ', '')

In [115]: search_string
Out[115]: ';Q8CCS6'

In [116]: df
Out[116]:
               Proteins
0                Q64HY3
1  G3UX74;G3UY42;Q8CCS6
2                Q8BKC5
3                O70209
4  Q8BG32;G3UYI4;G3UYL3

In [117]: df[df['Proteins'].str.contains(search_string, na=False)]
Out[117]:
               Proteins
1  G3UX74;G3UY42;Q8CCS6
```

Explanation:

```
In [135]: search_string = ';              Q8CCS6 '

In [136]: no_space_in_string = sum(c.isprintable() for c in search_string)

In [137]: no_space_in_string
Out[137]: 22

In [138]: search_string[:no_space_in_string]
Out[138]: ';              Q8CCS6 '

In [139]: ' '.isprintable()
Out[139]: True
```

Comment: yes but by this : search_string = search_string[:no_space_in_string] I get the same string back, it is just to remove spaces that the user might enter, or?

Comment: @user5875384, no - this way you will just slice your string, so it will work only under specific circumstances

Comment: thanks !  I have tried the replace(' ','') before however it was not efficient in removing spaces from an Entry widget in tkinter. But I hope can avoid somehow the is.printable() summarizing. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Ah now I know the problem ... I guess for trying to search I copied from an Excel Sheet on which the printable worked fine, nut the replace space doesnt. If I write manually the search_string in the Entry widget the replace approach works at it shoud. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @user5875384, you may remove nonprintables this way: `search_string = ''.join([c for c in list(search_string) if c.isprintable() and c!= ' '])`